# Largest product out of 4 in a grid

Tags: python

I'm doing some project euler problems to practice more. I am at problem 11 and I keep getting the wrong answer.

Here is the list of lists:

```
problem_11 = [[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8],
              [49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0],
              [81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65],
              [52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91],
              [22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80],
              [24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50],
              [32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70],
              [67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21],
              [24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72],
              [21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95],
              [78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92],
              [16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57],
              [86, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58],
              [19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40],
              [4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66],
              [88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69],
              [4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36],
              [20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16],
              [20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54],
              [1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48]
]
```

Here is the code:

```
def largest_product_grid(grid):
    greatest = 0
    patterns = [
        [(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
        [(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3)],
        [(0, -1), (0, -2), (0, -3)],
        [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
        [(-1, -1), (-2, -2), (-3, -3)]]
    for y in range(0, 19):
        for x in range(0, 19):
            for p in patterns:
                product = grid[y][x] * grid[p[0][1]][p[0][0]] * grid[p[1][1]][p[1][0]] * grid[p[2][1]][p[2][0]]
                if greatest < product:
                    greatest = product
    return greatest
```

I'm pretty sure it's doing more calculations than it needs to, doing the same math several times and going further on both x and y than I probably need to go. Yet I still keep getting the wrong answer. The correct should be: 70600674.

Edit: Question:

> "What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same
>   direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?"

I was expecting index out of range errors, yet I oversaw a stupid error.

Comment: What is project Euler problem 11? This isn't a project Eurler support site. Questions must contain problem specifications.

Comment: Note that you have five patterns to cover four directions.  Your third and fourth cover the same locations, but in opposite directions -- once you fix the indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you want your search pattern to be a function of x and y.

```
product = grid[y][x] * grid[p[0][1]][p[0][0]] * grid[p[1][1]][p[1][0]] * grid[p[2][1]][p[2][0]]
```

Right now, p[0][1] will always return the same value no matter what x and y are. You should replace the above line with something like:

```
product = grid[y][x] * grid[y + p[0][1]][x + p[0][0]] * grid[y + p[1][1]][x + p[1][0]] * grid[y + p[2][1]][x + p[2][0]]
```

Comment: sigh.. right, that was correct. For some reason in my mind those where there.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to the best of us :P